# How to reverse query for a record, returning all of its parent and their parents?

Tags: postgresql

Suppose the following,

```
create schema if not exists my_schema;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_schema.category (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    category_name VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    subcategories BIGINT[] DEFAULT ARRAY[]::BIGINT[]
);
```

```
INSERT INTO my_schema.category VALUES
    (
        1,
        'Pickup/dropoff',
        '{}'
    ),
    (
        2,
        'Electrician',
        '{}'
    ),
    (
        3,
        'Around the house',
        '{2}'
    ),
    (
        4,
        'Personal',
        '{3}'
    );
```

I'm trying to create breadcrumbs on the frontend. For instance, if `Electrician` is the selected category, I'd like to render something like `Personal > Around the house > Electrician`.

Ideally, I'd like the query to return something like,

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "breadcrumbs": "Personal.Around the house.Electrician"
}
```

This way, I could just do `breadcrumbs.split('.').map(. . .)`.

Another result that would work is something like,

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "category_name": "Electrician"
    "breadcrumbs": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "category_name": "Personal"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "category_name": "Around the house"
        },
    ]
}
```

Or even,

```
{
    "breadcrumbs": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "category_name": "Personal"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "category_name": "Around the house"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "category_name": "Electrician"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I attain such a result?

Comment: You'll need a recursive query. Notice it'll be easier if you don't store the sub-category relations in a separate table instead of an array.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, I'm not storing them in a separate table, as you can see

Comment: Then you'll need to do a query on the `subcategories` array. What exactly do you have trouble with, the idea of the recursive query or the matching against the array to find a parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using `WITH RECURSIVE` as follows :

to get any breadcrumbs just put its id on the first select `where id = 2`

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte(n, id, selectedCat) AS
(
  SELECT 1, id, id::text
  from category 
  where id = 2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n+1, e.id, ep.selectedCat
  FROM cte AS ep JOIN category AS e
      ON ep.id = ANY (e.subcategories)
)
SELECT selectedCat, string_agg(category_name, ',') as breadcrumbs FROM (
  SELECT selectedCat, category_name
  FROM cte 
  inner join category c on c.id = cte.id
  order by n desc
) AS s
GROUP BY selectedCat
```

[demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/zu7Ss1wh)